# Django Form: Validate line by line

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm creating a form where user input a bunch of email addresses.
What I want to do is to validate the emails line by line in TextField.

So what I need to do is to read the input line by line and apply email validator for each line.

How could I do it?

my current code (it's just normal Email form though..)

`forms.py`

```
class InputEmailsForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # override label and error messages here
        ...
```

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're asking. Are you asking how to parse user input that contains multiple e-mail addresses? If so, what format do you expect for this input? Or are you asking how to include multiple TextFields in a form?

Comment: @Sam user is supposed to input email address line by line in one TextField.

Comment: What is the expected format of this input? E.g., will the user separate e-mails by commas? Semicolons? Spaces? A "new line" character?

Comment: @Sam "new line" character like  example@example.com/nexample@example.com...

Comment: Got it. Can you share the source of your forms.py?

Comment: @Sam Sure but my current code is just EmailField. I need to find a way to read input line by line first.

Comment: Whatever you have, please share it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your EmailField (which would only accept one address) to a TextField, then write a custom validation function that uses Django's built-in validate_email function to check to ensure that each line contains a valid e-mail address:

```
from django.core.validators import validate_email
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django import forms

class InputEmailsForm(forms.Form):
    emails = forms.TextField()

    def clean_emails(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['emails']

        for line in data.splitlines():
            try validate_email(line):
                pass
            except ValidationError:
                raise forms.ValidationError("The following is not a valid e-mail: {0}".format(line))

        return data
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know `splitlines`. I will try this.